# Unable to sent dynamic forms to Google maps place_changed event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Javascript with Google Map V3 APIs for my application.
my code

```
for(var i = 0; i < viaName.length; i++) {
    // some other code......
    google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.forms[i+1].txtVia)); 
    autocomplete[i+1].bindTo('bounds', map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
        doSomething(document.forms[i+1]); } ); 
}
```

Where vaiName is an array.

I have multple forms on my page, and in them I have textboxes which are binded with autocomplete to predict text. What I want is call doSomething() function when ever the text is changed in any textboxes on the page (hence used multiple forms, having textbox in it)

Problem is that the function call `doSomething(document.forms[i+1]);` always gets viaName.length.

Example if viaName.length = 4 then no matter whichever textbox (in any forms)triggered the event doSomething function gets the `document.forms[4]` of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If viaName.length = 4, then 1 through 4 will always be passed to the doSomething function, from what I can see from your code above.  There is no if statement stopping it, it will iterate through 0 to 3 in the for statement provided above when viaName.length = 4, and it will pass doSomething [1, 2, 3, then 4].  That is all I can see from the code provided.

Comment: Thanks for response Smith, I know that but I want doSomething function to be called when event(place_change) event is occurred and want to pass the object of form from which this event has occured. As I mentioned earlier, I am using for loop since I have multiple forms and by this code I am expecting that for loop will just bind listener to pass form object to doSomething function. Correct me if am wrong ??

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing now.  So, from what I gather every time the event place_changed occurs it is always thinking that you are in document.forms[4]?  If this is the case, you have an issue when the addListener is being attached to your autocomplete box.  From a rough glance of a couple lines of code it looks like you need to create a NEW autocomplete each time as you are just overriding the same one as you are iterating, which makes you end up with 4 the last iteration of your for loop.  Hopefully, not leading you astray just tough to see from the code you currently have listed.